# Cordova Background Fetcher plugin not working for iOS

Tags: cordova, ios7, plugins

I would like to implement this plugin: https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-fetch. I installed the plugin using CLI, then copied the BackgroundFetch.js file to my www directory and referenced it in index.html. I placed the sample code as given in the git url in the DeviceReady function. Still, on startup I am faced with the error:

**TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'Fetcher.configure')**

Can someone please tell me why this is happening? I've been trying for two days now but to no avail. Any help will be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

**EDIT1:** Sorry I didn't mention it earlier, I created a cordova project using the command line and added the plugin as described above, then ran it both on the iOS Simulator and on an iPhone 4S. Both give the same error.I wrapped the code in a try-catch block and alerted the error,this was the error that came.

After seeing Clawish's suggestion, I removed the js file and the reference to it, and removed and added the plugin again. Now I don't get any errors, but I don't see "CDVBackgroundFetch configure" in the logs. If I simulate a background fetch on the simulator, I get the error: - 
CDVBackgroundFetch onFetch 
Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called. 
Where am I going wrong? I haven't made any changes to the code except adding the sample code to call Fetcher.configure in onDeviceReady

---

**EDIT2:**

After seeing your Clawfish's second edit, I removed the service call and shortened the function as below:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

var Fetcher = window.plugins.backgroundFetch;

// Your background-fetch handler.
var fetchCallback = function() {
    console.log('BackgroundFetch initiated');
    Fetcher.finish();
}
Fetcher.configure(fetchCallback);
},
```

Still, I don't see any log message saying "CDVBackgroundFetch configure" and on simulating Background fetch the same warning comes as above. It seems the Fetch part is being executed without it running configure in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit2:** I guess you have added the whole sample code from the docs (with decalaration of `var Fetcher` and the handler `var fetchCallback` and after declaring both, you run `Fetcher.configure(fetchCallback);`.
The problem might be that you don't have jQuery referenced in your `index.html` and the code stops running when it sees the line `$.get(...)`. If that is the case, [download](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js) jQuery, put it into your `www` folder, and reference it from your `index.html`.
Do you see the console message `console.log('BackgroundFetch initiated');`? What about `/heartbeat.json`, did you change that?

---

**Edit:** You don't need to copy the BackgroundFetch.js to your `www` directory, and you also don't need to reference it in your `index.html`. Try to remove the reference in your `index.html` and leave the plugin files untouched after installing. If you have changed something regarding the file structure you should `cordova plugin remove` the plugin and `add` it again afterwards.

---

I don't know from which console you are recieving this error. If it is a browser console, like Chrome, then no wonders, since the Fetcher does only work on an iDevice (or iOS-simulator).
And the Cordova Console plugin does not print such messages.

Try to use the code in the iOS simulator.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it, I created a cordova project using the command line and added the plugin as described above, then ran it both on the iOS Simulator and on an iPhone 4S. Both give the same error.

Comment: I wrapped the code in a try-catch block and alerted the error,this is the error that comes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I removed the js file and the reference to it, and removed and added the plugin again. Now I don't get any errors, but I don't see "CDVBackgroundFetch configure" in the logs. If I simulate a background fetch on the simulator, I get the error: 
- CDVBackgroundFetch onFetch

Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

Where am I going wrong? I haven't made any changes to the code except adding the sample code to call Fetcher.configure in onDeviceReady.

Comment: Thanks so much Clawfish for all your help. I modified the DeviceReady code as pasted above, the error still persists. =/

Comment: Does your `deviceReady` event fire? I. e. do you have a `document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);`?

Comment: Yes I have that line in my code. And the event fires too, I placed an alert inside it and I was able to see that alert on app startup.